# How to disable "renew" option for canceled plans on Billing Portal?

Tags: stripe-payments

I am using Stripe and [Billing Portal](https://stripe.com/blog/billing-customer-portal).

If the user has canceled subscriptions in the past, then Billing Portal displays a list of canceled subscriptions and offers the option to renew for each canceled subscription:

[image]

The problem is that this allows users to subscribe to the same or different membership multiple times. For example, if I want my website to offer three types of membership:

- Pro
- Premium
- Gold

and users can only be subscribed to one type of membership at a time - Billing Portal with that "renew" option allows user to subscribe to the two or more memberships (subscription plans) at a time: Lets say that user first subscribes to "Premium", then he cancels it... Then subscribes again to "Premium"... On Billing Portal he will be able to "renew" (subscribe) to "Premium" again...

Is it possible to disable (remove) that "renew" button (option)? I was looking into settings but couldn't find anything: https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/settings/billing/portal

Also I couldn't find anything in the documentation, [FAQ section](https://support.stripe.com/questions/billing-customer-portal), etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because those subscriptions are set to cancel at period end, rather than immediately. They are not actually cancelled yet and can be reactivated. How are you cancelling these subscriptions?

If cancelling yourself via the API, make sure you aren't using `cancel_at_period_end` ([API ref](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/update#update_subscription-cancel_at_period_end)) and instead [cancel immediately](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/cancel).

If you're letting customers cancel via portal, make sure to set the cancellation `mode=immediately` ([API ref](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customer_portal/configuration#portal_configuration_object-features-subscription_cancel-mode)).

Similar options should be available if cancelled via the dashboard.

Once in this state (say if it were what you wanted), you can limit the portal session to only apply to a specific [product/price](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customer_portal/configuration#portal_configuration_object-features-subscription_update-products). So you'd need to determine which of your gold/pro products was the active/new plan and create a portal configuration that only allowed updates for subscriptions for that product/price.

Comment: Thank you Brendan.